# Cypher query for externalized property values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

in our data model we have externalized some of our domain entities values into external nodes. The model for a service object looks like:

```
ref=node(0), 
ref<-[:SERVICE]-subRefNode<-[:SERVICE]-aService-[:HAS_PROPERTY_VALUE]->propValueNode-[:IS_OF_TYPE]->propDefType,
ref<-[:SERVICE]-subRefNode-[:HAS_PROPERTY]->propDefType
```

The node subRefNode holds a relationship to all services. All possible properties for a service are defined through ref<-[:SERVICE]-subRefNode-[:HAS_PROPERTY]->propDefType. So it could be that a certain node doesn't have a propValueNode yet for a certain property (e.g. a comment) and others might have one but its empty (the user might have entered a comment and then cleared it).

So my question is how do I get the nodes with an empty propValueNode.value and also the ones that do not have a propertyValueNode yet? I thought about something like...

```
START ref=node(0) MATCH ref<-[:SERVICE]-subRef, aService-[pvRel?:HAS_PROPERTY_VALUE]->propValueNode-[pdRel:IS_OF_TYPE]->propDef<-[:HAS_PROPERTY]-subRef<-[:SERVICE]-aService WHERE (pvRel IS NOT NULL AND propDef.name = 'comment' AND propValueNode.value=~"^$") OR (pvRel IS NULL AND pdRel IS NULL AND propDef.name="comment") RETURN DISTINCT aService.debug
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/7zeoay

...but this misses the ones without a propValueNode. Any hints are appreciated!

Regards,
Andi

If http://console.neo4j.org/r/7zeoay is not valid anymore, here's the initial graph setup:

```
start _0 = node(0) with _0 
create
(_1  {type:"SubReferenceNode", name:"SubRef"}),

(_2  {type:"Service", debug:"S0 empty value"}),
(_3  {type:"Service", debug:"S1 missing value node"}),
(_4  {type:"Service", debug:"S2 with value"}),

(_5  {type:"PropertyDefintion", name:"comment"}),
(_6  {type:"PropertyDefintion", name:"name"}),

(_7  {type:"PropertyValue", value:"S0 empty value"}),
(_8  {type:"PropertyValue", value:"S1 missing value node"}),
(_9 {type:"PropertyValue", value:"S2 with value"}),

(_10  {type:"PropertyValue", value:""}),
(_11 {type:"PropertyValue", value:"This is a comment"}),

_0<-[:SERVICE]-_1,
_1<-[:SERVICE]-_2,
_1<-[:SERVICE]-_3,
_1<-[:SERVICE]-_4,

_1-[:HAS_PROPERTY]->_5,
_1-[:HAS_PROPERTY]->_6,

_2-[:HAS_PROPERTY_VALUE]->_7,
_7-[:IS_OF_TYPE]->_6,
_3-[:HAS_PROPERTY_VALUE]->_8,
_8-[:IS_OF_TYPE]->_6,
_4-[:HAS_PROPERTY_VALUE]->_9,
_9-[:IS_OF_TYPE]->_6,

_2-[:HAS_PROPERTY_VALUE]->_10,
_10-[:IS_OF_TYPE]->_5,
_4-[:HAS_PROPERTY_VALUE]->_11,
_11-[:IS_OF_TYPE]->_5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine two queries, one is to return the service which has an empty value for the property "comment", and another returns the service which does not have a propery value that is of the type "comment", in other word, none of the service property values is of the the type "comment".

```
START ref=node(0) 
MATCH ref<-[:SERVICE]-subRef, aService-[pvRel?:HAS_PROPERTY_VALUE]->propValueNode-[pdRel:IS_OF_TYPE]->propDef<-[:HAS_PROPERTY]-subRef<-[:SERVICE]-aService 
WHERE (pvRel IS NOT NULL AND propDef.name = 'comment' AND propValueNode.value=~"^$") 
RETURN DISTINCT aService.debug
UNION
START ref=node(0)
MATCH ref<-[:SERVICE]-subRef, aService-[pvRel:HAS_PROPERTY_VALUE]->propValueNode-[pdRel:IS_OF_TYPE]->propDef<-[:HAS_PROPERTY]-subRef<-[:SERVICE]-aService
with aService, collect(propDef.name) as propNames
WHERE NONE( propName in propNames where propName = 'comment')
RETURN DISTINCT aService.debug
```

The alternative solution without using the "UNION" clause is to get all value nodes for each service and returns only those service that either none of its values is of type "comment" or there is one value of the type "comment" and the value is empty, as shown in the "Where" clause below,

```
START ref=node(0) 
MATCH ref<-[:SERVICE]-subRef, aService-[pvRel:HAS_PROPERTY_VALUE]->propValueNode-[pdRel?:IS_OF_TYPE]->propDef<-[:HAS_PROPERTY]-subRef<-[:SERVICE]-aService 
WHERE propDef.name = 'comment' 
WITH aService, collect(propValueNode) AS valueNodes, propDef 
WHERE NONE (v IN valueNodes 
            WHERE v-[:IS_OF_TYPE]->propDef) OR SINGLE (v IN valueNodes 
                                                       WHERE v.value=~"^$" AND v-[:IS_OF_TYPE]->propDef) 
RETURN aService.debug
```

Comment: Unfortunately in the stable version (1.9.3), there is no UNION yet. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I added an alternative query that does not use "UNION" so that you can run with the version 1.9.3